# The driver is not unable to locate the element defaultCurrency by xpath.!

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

The driver is not unable to locate the element defaultCurrency by xpath.

Error -"org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with."

**Code:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='currency']/fieldset[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")).click();

WebElement defaultCurrency = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='defaultCurrency']"));

Select defaultCurrency_Select = new Select(defaultCurrency); defaultCurrency_Select.selectByVisibleText("USD");
```

**Source Code:**

```
<td>
    <select id="defaultCurrency" class="validate[required]" onchange="javascript:clrErrors()" style="height:25px;width:160px;" name="defCurrency.defaultCurrency">    
        <option value="">Select Currency..</option>
        <option value="INR">GBP</option>
        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        <option value="USD">USD</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure there is no other code that interacts with this `select`? Any javascript or CSS that hides it or shows it depending on a users action? Is it visible on page load or do you have to do something on the page to get it appear?

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver throw `ElementNotVisibleException` exception only when element is not visibile. Therefore, have a look at the element, (e.g. via Firebug) and note which element is activating him as to be visible. Then try to activate the first element, and then operate on desired one. Or maybe element is designed to be invisibile at that specific moment, so you should not be allowed to perform actions on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Select currency = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("Select[id="defaultCurrency"]")));
```